# compare chart series array with new array to determine adds/removes

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js, highcharts

I am writing a knockout binding for highcharts, and I therefore have an observable array of highcharts `series` objects which I want to bind to the chart by adding and/or removing series as necessary using the [highcharts api](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.id).

Here is the outline of my `bindingHandler` (for the non-knockout out there, this is the bit which ties my ViewModel to the UI element bound to it).

```
ko.bindingHandlers.series = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        if(element.highChart === undefined){
            console.warn('Element ' + element.id + ' not attached to a highchart binding');
            return;
        }
        var value = valueAccessor();
        var valueUnwrapped = ko.unwrap(value);
        var chart = element.highChart;
        var series = chart.series;
        if($.isArray(valueUnwrapped)){
            // In here is my question
        }
    }
}
```

Where the comment is above formsa the crux of my qustion. At this point I have two javascript variables

- `series` - an array of highcharts series objects *currently* displayed
- `valueUnwrapped` - an array of highcharts series objects which *should now* be displayed

What would be an efficient way of comparing these two arrays to determine

- which instances on the `series` array which should be removed using the [`remove` method](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.remove)
- which instances on the `valueUnwrapped` array which should be added using the [`addSeries` method](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.addSeries)

In case its of help, there is a useful looking [`get` method](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.get) which gets a series by id, and I'm happy to have an id on all my series. That is on the `chart` object which you will also see in my example code above.

I could of course be really lazy and clear the chart

```
while(series.length > 0)
     series[0].remove(false);
```

then add them again from my array. I'm wondering if there's perhaps a better way.

Comment: doesn't knockout observes changes for you, so you don't have to manually reconcile?

Comment: Thats what im trying to add ;) knockout will bind text to a textbox, and items to a dropdown natively, but when you want to integrate something like highcharts, you write a [bindingHandler](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html)

Comment: is your series data array composed of numbers, arrays, or objects?

Comment: its an array of [highcharts series objects](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series)

Comment: that's what i was afraid of. if it were numbers or arrays, you can compare the series elements as strings, but objects are much harder to compare. you'll need to find the smoking gun properties to id the whole object. That could be the name or the value depending on your data. There's not enough info here to answer definitively...

Comment: im happy with series name in the above case.

Comment: no, not the series name, the name of each object in the series, if that's what's changing. Sometimes one wants to add new elements with new names, sometimes the names stay the same but the values update. Whichever your approach, match up the one that stays the same, and exclude the one that is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, that the 'lazy' way isn't that lazy at all. Even if you set for each series 'id' then `get()` function from Highcharts will loop over all series to find one. And if you have 10 series, you will do the for-loop 10x times. In the fact it checks also axis and points, so it's not as fast as you may expect.

I would stick to

```
while(series.length > 0)
   series[0].remove(false);

$(valueUnwrapped).each(function(el, in){
    chart.addSeries(el, false);
});

chart.redraw();
```

Since that's all: only two 'for' loops with nice performance. While checking and comparing if series need to be removed or updated or just new data set isn't worth of it (in my opinion).

I think you can try to create new question for knockout (without highcharts tag) something like: 'how to compare two array of objects based on ID's' os something like that ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that is pretty much what I went with.